# Theming login form just for specific user registration / Auto Assign Role Page

Tags: 7, users, theming

On [this page](http://bo-medical.com/benl/doctor-signup) users gets automatically a role assigned by the [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module.

For a better user experience i added the login form also to this page. This works great:

In `user--register.tpl.php` I added the following code to print the login-form `<?php print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block'))); ?>`

But how do i THEME this login form on this specific page? So it doesn't affect the original form on `/user/login`?

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the *user_login_block* within your template, which is not rendered on the `/user/login` page.

As long as you have not placed a login-block, that you don't want to be affected, you should not have any problems.

You can use the template file `block--user--login.tpl.php` to theme this block or even use a `form_alter` hook to alter the form.